# How to optimize indexing in elastic search?

Tags: php, node.js, search, elasticsearch, search-engine

we are working on eCommerce project and trying to implement elastic search as a search engine and its working fine in search .

But now its time to index data to elastic search and we have very frequent updates in data so its not a good option to index data every time from php because it can face delay in output

so what can we do to index data without compromising with user experience.

is node js a better option for that?
can node js update data asynchronously without compromising with user experience ?

Answer (score 0):

You should decouple your frontend-serving from the ES indexing. This can for example be achieved if you post the indexing request to a message queue, such as RabbitMQ, and then have a worker process listening to that queue which actually triggers the ES indexing.

See

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html

Comment: First of all very tnx for you answer 

is it fruitfull to use node js rather than Quieng system?

Comment: That is a very open question which is not really suitable for SO